# The elegant way to replace specific characters in Python

Tags: python, replace, char

I have strings that are unpredictable in terms of character content, but I know that every string contains exactly one character '*'.

How to replace two characters after the '*' with some non hard-coded string. Non hard-coded string is actually calculated checksum and converted into string:

```
checksum_str = str(hex(csum).lstrip('0x'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
star_pos = my_string.find('*')
my_string = my_string[:star_pos] + '*' + checksum_str + my_string[star_pos + 3:]
```

Comment: Exactly that!! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
import re
my_string = re.sub(r'(?<=\*)..', checksum_str, my_string, 1)
```

Comment: this doesnt replace, this inserts the string